# EditText does not allow to delete text set programatically

Tags: android, text, android-edittext, backspace

I made EditText as you can see below. Unfortunately, when I test this on my LG G3, EditText does not allow me to delete any part of text which was set by setText(). I can select this text and then delete it by typing something, but I don't understand why I can not simply delete `contentView.getPath()` by pressing backspace on soft keyboard. I can also type any text anywhere and delete typed text, but not the text that was set programmatically.

```java
private void pathBox(){
    final EditText pathField = requestTyping(); //returns previously styled EditText
    pathField.setHint(R.string.goto_hint);
    pathField.setText(contentView.getPath(), BufferType.EDITABLE);
    pathField.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);
    pathField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    pathField.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event){
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                    || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                contentView.setPath(pathField.getText().toString());
                pathField.clearFocus();
                AppUI.hideKeyboard(v);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    AppUI.showKeyboardFor(pathField);
}
```

Whole problem looks like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FyE67JAcGC4
What should I do to enable edit, modification and deletion of all EditTexts' content?

Comment: Have you tried `pathField.setText("");`?

Comment: Tried setting your editText text using just setText(contentView.getPath()); ?

Comment: I changed standard setText(String) to setText(String, BufferType) because standard way seemed not to work. However everything looks fine on Bluestacks emulator.
I want to display path that can be modified, so I do as in code I attached. I am going to upload short video that demonstrates how does it look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS` flag was the cause of problems. When removed, everything works as it should, except the fact that user may struggle with unnecessary "hints" given by autocorrect and dictionary.